# Connect label to an outlet in XCode 5

Tags: ios, xcode5

I have updated to XCode 5 and I cannot connect a label to an outlet using the old way: ctrl-drag from Connections inspector to the table view cell. No popup appears

In my tableview I have a ArticleCell with two labels:

```
@interface ArticleCell : UITableViewCell
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UILabel *title;
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UILabel *date;
@end
```

I want to connect those two labels to this outlets. Is there a different way to do it in XCode 5 ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you set the *"Custom Class"* of your table view cell in your storyboard or XIB file to "`ArticleCell`", you should be able to control drag your outlets to your labels again.

Comment: I already did that. What is strange is when I drag to the cell, the all tableview gets selected, not the cell. So I guess something I'm doing wrong

Comment: Ok, I fixed it, I didn't see that it was a typo in my program

Comment: That happens to me sometimes, too.  Just need an extra pair of eyes once in a while.

Comment: @MichaelDautermann Is there a different approach when mapping a label in a table view cell as compared to when not in a cell?